# how can I make cvxpy to support 3d variable

Tags: cvxpy, mixed-integer-programming

I have an mixed integer problem which evolves 3d variables. I would like to define variables like:
X = cvxpy.Variables((n,m,T))

And set constraints using slicing operation like in numpy:

b*cvxpy.sum(X[:,j,:],axis=1) ＜= 1

And some other even complex expression as constraints.
However, cvxpy does not support N＞2 D variables. The question is, is there any alternative package I can use to support this demand? Or any efficient techniques I can adopt to easily implement it. Thanks for any suggestions you may give me.

Comment: cvxpy is based on numpy/scipy and therefore this limitation as scipy has sparse matrices and not sparse tensors or generalizations. While sparse-matrices are well-researched with common base-patterns used everywhere (e.g. csc, csr formats), higher-dimensions are much more tricky and much less general-purpose. So no: i don't think you will find an alternative package, at least no cvxpy-compatible one (as it must hide this from cvxpy). Furthermore you should exploit what you know (sparsity-pattern) and *decompose yourself* (e.g. list of sparse matrix) fitting your task.

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer. Additionally, how can I write an expression of constraints as, if variable_a ≠ variable_b, then variable_c=1, without violates DCP rule in cvxpy.